# How to re-enable on-screen keyboard if the maximum length is not met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a ul li keyboard that gets 4 numbers first, 3 letters next and then disables itself. However, if the user clicks the delete button, it won't re-enable itself.

I thought "If I just add .removeClass('disabled') if the length is less than 8, it might work. But I'm pretty sure that's not how this works. Please help me out.

```js
$(function() {
  var $write = $('#write'),
    symbols = $('.symbol'),
    letters = $('.letter'),
    shift = false,
    capslock = false;

  $('#keyboard li').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      character = $this.html(); // If it's a lowercase letter, nothing happens to this variable

    // Shift keys
    if ($this.hasClass('left-shift') || $this.hasClass('right-shift')) {
      $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
      $('.symbol span').toggle();

      shift = (shift === true) ? false : true;
      capslock = false;
      return false;
    }

    // Caps lock
    if ($this.hasClass('capslock')) {
      $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
      capslock = true;
      return false;
    }

    // Delete
    if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
      var html = $write.html();
      $write.html(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));
      return false;
    }

    // Special characters
    if ($this.hasClass('symbol')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
    if ($this.hasClass('space')) character = ' ';
    if ($this.hasClass('tab')) character = "\t";
    if ($this.hasClass('return')) character = "\n";

    // Uppercase letter
    if ($this.hasClass('uppercase')) character = character.toUpperCase();

    // Remove shift once a key is clicked.
    if (shift === true) {
      $('.symbol span').toggle();
      if (capslock === false) $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');

      shift = false;
    }


    $write.html($write.html() + character);
    text1 = document.getElementById('write').value;
    console.log(text1);
    if (text1.length >= 4) {
      symbols.addClass('disabled');
      letters.removeClass('disabled');
      if (text1.length == 7) {
        letters.addClass('disabled');


      }

    }
    if (text1.length > 7) {
      letters.removeClass('disabled');
    }





    // Add the character

  });
});
```

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.maincontainer {
  background-image: url(b.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: right;
}


/*head*/

.nav-text {
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
}

.row {
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.back-button {
  height: 100%;
}

#backer {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
}

.red {
  background-color: darkred;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
}

.uk-icon {
  color: white;
}


/*main*/


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  background-color: darkred;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#tabone {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

#tabtwo {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(80, 3, 3);
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: rgb(180, 15, 15);
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  background-color: white;
}

#London {
  text-align: center;
}

#searchbutton {
  background-color: darkred;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

#write {
  width: 90%;
  height: 300px;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/Soyombo_red.svg/300px-Soyombo_red.svg.png) no-repeat scroll 50px 40px;
  background-size: 80PX;
  padding-left: 50px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10vh;
}

#London>.container-fluid>h3 {
  margin-top: 5%;
  font-size: 4vh;
}

#keyboard {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}

#keyboard li {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: 5%;
  padding: 0;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7PX;
  ;
}

#keyboard .delete {
  width: 120px;
}

.lastitem {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.on {
  display: none;
}

#keyboard li:hover {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  border-color: #e5e5e5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#container.ul {
  margin: auto;
  float: center;
}

#container-x {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background: url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Y/3/d/w/R/r/search-icon-white-hi.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 25%;
  background-position-y: 50%;
  background-position-x: 10%;
}

.disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

  <title>
    Payment
  </title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-keyboard@latest/build/css/index.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- UIkit CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.3/css/uikit.min.css" />
  <!-- UIkit JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.3/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.3/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <!-- My CSS & JS-->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="container-fluid red">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-">
          <div class="back-button">
            <a id="backer" class="uk-button uk-button-default" href="#"><span uk-icon="icon:arrow-left;"></span><span class="nav-text">Эхлэх</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl">
          <div class="header">
            Тээврийн хэрэгслийн торгууль төлөх
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-">
          <div class="header">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="uk-container">
      <img style="width: auto;">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="tab">
          <button uk-icon="bus" class="tablinks" id="tabone" onclick="openTab(event, 'London')">ТЭЭВРИЙН ХЭРЭГСЭЛ</button>
          <button class="tablinks" id="tabtwo" onclick="openTab(event, 'Paris')">ЖОЛООНЫ ҮНЭМЛЭХ</button>
        </div>
        <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <h3>АВТОМАШИНЫ УЛСЫН ДУГААР</h3>
            <div id="input_container">
              <textarea type="text" required id="write" maxLength="4" placeholder="UBA0000"></textarea>


            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Хайх" id="searchbutton" class="uk-button uk-button-default" href="#"></input>
          </div>

          <div style="width:auto;margin: auto;" id="container">
            <ul style="display:table; width:100%;" id="keyboard">
              <li class="symbol"><span class="off">1</span></li>
              <li class="symbol"><span class="off">2</span></li>
              <li class="symbol"><span class="off">3</span></li>
              <li class="symbol"><span class="off">4</span></li>
              <li class="symbol"><span class="off">5</span></li>
              <li class="symbol"><span class="off">6</span></li>
              <li class="symbol"><span class="off">7</span></li>
              <li class="symbol"><span class="off">8</span></li>
              <li class="symbol"><span class="off">9</span></li>
              <li class="symbol"><span class="off">0</span></li>
              <li class="delete"><span class="delete"><img style="width:50%"
                                                                src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/sympletts-part-1/128/backspace-256.png"></span></li>
              <br>
              <li class="letter disabled">Ф</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Ц</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">У</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Ж</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Э</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Н</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Г</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Ш</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Ү</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">З</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">К</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Ъ</li><br>
              <li class="letter disabled">Й</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Ы</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Б</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Ө</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">А</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Х</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Р</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">О</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Л</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Д</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">П</li><br>
              <li class="letter disabled">Я</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Ч</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Е</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Ё</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">С</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">М</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">И</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Т</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Ь</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">В</li>
              <li class="letter disabled">Ю</li>
            </ul>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>Paris</h3>

      </div>
      <script>
        function openTab(evt, tabName) {
          var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
          tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
          for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
          }
          tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
          for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
          }
          document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
          evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        }
      </script>



    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Kind of does what it needs to do except it's missing a vital function. Am not experienced enough to work around this.
(p.s This keyboard literally does not care about textarea character limits as it's not onkeypress, i don't know what it is. So I just put in some improvisations to work around. If you just write on it with your keyboard, it's going to type at most 4 letters as that is the limit on the text area. If you write it with the on-screen keyboard, you're going to get 7. Help?)

(P.S.S : ALSO WHY DOES THE "LEFT-TAB" KEEP GOING UPWARDS WHEN MINIMIZED?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought "If I just add .removeClass('disabled') if the length is less than 8, it might work. But I'm pretty sure that's not how this works.

This does not work because when you handle delete button, you have used "`return false;`" which means it will return at there and not continue run your code to the `.removeClass('disabled')` part.

My solution is you need to handle the add and remove disabled in delete function like below:

```
// Delete
if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
    var html = $write.html();
    $write.html(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));

    //get text1 value from textarea
    text1 = document.getElementById('write').value;

    //When length < 4, just enable numbers, disable letters
    if (text1.length < 4)
    {
        symbols.removeClass('disabled');
        letters.addClass('disabled'); 
    }

    //When length >= 4, handle like your current code
    if (text1.length >= 4)
    {
        symbols.addClass('disabled');
        letters.removeClass('disabled'); 
         if(text1.length == 7){
            letters.addClass('disabled');

        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

So in the delete part, you will handle the disable on your virtual keyboard.

And since that, you can remove this part in your code:

> `if (text1.length > 7) {
>         letters.removeClass('disabled');
>      }`

For the physical keyboard input, if you don't want the user using it, you can set 
`maxLength="0"` in the textarea part.

```
<textarea type="text" required id="write" maxLength="0" placeholder="UBA0000"></textarea>
```

Please check demo below to see how it works.

Happy coding time :D.

```js
$(function(){
  var $write = $('#write'),
  symbols = $('.symbol'),
  letters = $('.letter'),
  shift = false,
  capslock = false;
 
 $('#keyboard li').click(function(){
  var $this = $(this),
   character = $this.html(); // If it's a lowercase letter, nothing happens to this variable
  
  // Shift keys
  if ($this.hasClass('left-shift') || $this.hasClass('right-shift')) {
   $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
   $('.symbol span').toggle();
   
   shift = (shift === true) ? false : true;
   capslock = false;
   return false;
  }
  
  // Caps lock
  if ($this.hasClass('capslock')) {
   $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
   capslock = true;
   return false;
  }
  
  // Delete
  if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
   var html = $write.html();
   $write.html(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));

   //get text1 value from textarea
   text1 = document.getElementById('write').value;
   
   //When length < 4, just enable numbers, disable letters
   if (text1.length < 4)
   {
    symbols.removeClass('disabled');
    letters.addClass('disabled'); 
   }
   
   //When length >= 4, handle like your current code
   if (text1.length >= 4)
   {
    symbols.addClass('disabled');
    letters.removeClass('disabled'); 
     if(text1.length == 7){
     letters.addClass('disabled');
  
    }
   }
   return false;
  }
  
  // Special characters
  if ($this.hasClass('symbol')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
  if ($this.hasClass('space')) character = ' ';
  if ($this.hasClass('tab')) character = "\t";
  if ($this.hasClass('return')) character = "\n";
  
  // Uppercase letter
  if ($this.hasClass('uppercase')) character = character.toUpperCase();
  
  // Remove shift once a key is clicked.
  if (shift === true) {
   $('.symbol span').toggle();
   if (capslock === false) $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
   
   shift = false;
  }
  
  
   $write.html($write.html() + character);
   text1 = document.getElementById('write').value;
   console.log(text1);
   if (text1.length >= 4)
   {
    symbols.addClass('disabled');
    letters.removeClass('disabled'); 
     if(text1.length == 7){
     letters.addClass('disabled');
     
  
    }

   }
  
   

   

  // Add the character

 });
});
```

```css
html{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.maincontainer{
    background-image: url(b.png); 
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position: right;
}

/*head*/
.nav-text
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
}
.row
{
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.back-button
{
    height: 100%;
}

#backer
{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}
.red
{
    background-color: darkred;
}
.header
{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size:25px;
    float: left;
    width:90%;
}
.uk-icon
{
    color:white;
}
/*main*/
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
  .tab button {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    background-color: darkred;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  #tabone
  {
      border-top-left-radius: 5px; 
      border-right: 1px solid white;
  }
  #tabtwo
  {
      border-top-right-radius: 5px; 
      border-left: 1px solid white;
  }

  
  /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
  .tab button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(80, 3, 3);
  }
  
  /* Create an active/current tablink class */
  .tab button.active {
    background-color: rgb(180, 15, 15);
  }
  /* Style the tab content */
  .tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
    background-color: white;
  }
  #London
  {
    text-align: center;
  }
  #searchbutton
  {
      background-color: darkred;
      color: white;
      border:0;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      padding-right:20px;

  }
  #write
  {
      width: 90%;
      height:300px;
      background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/Soyombo_red.svg/300px-Soyombo_red.svg.png) no-repeat scroll 50px 40px;
      background-size: 80PX;
      padding-left:50px;
      border-radius: 5%;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      margin-top:20px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size:10vh;
  }

  #London > .container-fluid > h3{
      margin-top:5%;
      font-size: 4vh;
  }
  #keyboard {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
}

#keyboard li {
    font-size: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    width: 5%;
    padding: 0;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7PX;;
}

#keyboard .delete {
    width: 120px;
}

.lastitem {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.on {
    display: none;
}

#keyboard li:hover {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    border-color: #e5e5e5;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#container.ul{
    margin:auto;
    float: center;
}

#container-x
{
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}
input[type=submit]
{
    background:url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Y/3/d/w/R/r/search-icon-white-hi.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 25%;
    background-position-y: 50%;
    background-position-x: 10%;
}
.disabled
{
    opacity: 0.5;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>

        <title>
            Payment
        </title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-keyboard@latest/build/css/index.css">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">    
        <!-- UIkit CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.3/css/uikit.min.css" />
        <!-- UIkit JS -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.3/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.3/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <!-- My CSS & JS-->
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="maincontainer">
        <div class="container-fluid red">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-">        
                                    <div class="back-button">
                                            <a id="backer" class="uk-button uk-button-default" href="#"><span uk-icon="icon:arrow-left;"></span><span class="nav-text">Эхлэх</span></a>
                                        </div>                       
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xl">
                                <div class="header">
                                        Тээврийн хэрэгслийн торгууль төлөх
                                </div>
                                </div>   
                                <div class="col-">
                                        <div class="header">
                                        </div>   
                            </div>
                        </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="uk-container">
            <img style="width: auto;">
            <div class="box">
                    <div class="tab">
                            <button uk-icon="bus" class="tablinks" id="tabone" onclick="openTab(event, 'London')">ТЭЭВРИЙН ХЭРЭГСЭЛ</button>
                            <button class="tablinks" id="tabtwo" onclick="openTab(event, 'Paris')">ЖОЛООНЫ ҮНЭМЛЭХ</button>
                            </div>
                            <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <h3>АВТОМАШИНЫ УЛСЫН ДУГААР</h3>
                                        <div id="input_container">
                                                <textarea type="text" required id="write" maxLength="0" placeholder="UBA0000"></textarea>   
                                                
                                                                      
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                        <div>
                                           <input type="submit"  value="Хайх" id="searchbutton" class="uk-button uk-button-default" href="#"></input>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <div style="width:auto;margin: auto;" id="container">
                                                <ul style="display:table; width:100%;" id="keyboard">
                                                    <li class="symbol"><span class="off">1</span></li>
                                                    <li class="symbol"><span class="off">2</span></li>
                                                    <li class="symbol"><span class="off">3</span></li>
                                                    <li class="symbol"><span class="off">4</span></li>
                                                    <li class="symbol"><span class="off">5</span></li>
                                                    <li class="symbol"><span class="off">6</span></li>
                                                    <li class="symbol"><span class="off">7</span></li>
                                                    <li class="symbol"><span class="off">8</span></li>
                                                    <li class="symbol"><span class="off">9</span></li>
                                                    <li class="symbol"><span class="off">0</span></li>
                                                    <li class="delete"><span class="delete"><img style="width:50%"
                                                                src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/sympletts-part-1/128/backspace-256.png"></span></li>
                                                    <br>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Ф</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Ц</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">У</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Ж</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Э</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Н</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Г</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Ш</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Ү</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">З</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">К</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Ъ</li><br>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Й</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Ы</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Б</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Ө</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">А</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Х</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Р</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">О</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Л</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Д</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">П</li><br>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Я</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Ч</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Е</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Ё</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">С</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">М</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">И</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Т</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Ь</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">В</li>
                                                    <li class="letter disabled">Ю</li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  
                                  <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
                                    <h3>Paris</h3>
                                   
                                  </div>
                                  <script>
                                        function openTab(evt, tabName) {
                                          var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
                                          tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
                                          for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                                            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
                                          }
                                          tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
                                          for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
                                            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                                          }
                                          document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
                                          evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
                                        }
                                        </script>



            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi nimbleclouds, thank you for help me to corrected my poor grammar. I you need any other help on this please ask me. I will try to figure out with you.
Cheers :D